# Retrieve, only the contents from media wiki API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki

I would like to retrieve only the events in a hash from [February 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_14) wiki page

For that I am trying this [JSON API call](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=February%2014&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json) but it does not give clear information. How can I imrovise my api call to get all events list in a proper way. I would like to store this info in db as object like key, value pair.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters `prop=revisions`, `rvprop=content` and set `rvsection` ID to the API call. In your case, the section ID for `Events` is 1, so the API call will be:

[`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=February_14&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=February_14&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=1)

Comment: I can not store the information as it is in the db. IS there any possible way to get proper information by removing the brackets and ASCII characters?

Comment: @Jefferson what programming language are you using to retrieve the content and to storing it to a database? There are [several parsers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) which can be used to extract text from mediawiki format.

Comment: I am using node.js